# newbie keeps losing alpha values in canvas

Tags: html5-canvas, alpha

I'm probably doing something boneheaded here but I'm having difficulties getting alpha values to cooperate in Canvas.  I'm trying to sample an opaque color from a spot on the canvas, make it more transparent, and lay it down in another spot -- but the alpha part doesn't seem to be working.  Stripped down it goes sort of like this (condensed from functions strewn across the script):

```
p = ground.ctx.getImageData(loc.x, loc.y, 1, 1).data; 
col = {R: p[0], G: p[1], B: p[2], a: p[3]};
col.a = col.a - 0.1;
ground.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(' + col.R + ', ' + col.G + ', ' + col.B + ', ' + col.a + ')';
ground.ctx.fillRect(nuLoc.x, nuLoc.y, sqrSize, sqrSize);
```

It all runs, but when I test the value of fillStyle I get just a standard RGB "#fa674c" or whatever -- no mention of any alpha -- and when I getImageData() from the newly drawn Rect the value is fully opaque again.

Another thing I haven't been able to figure out either empirically or by reading every tutorial (and the spec) is whether alpha wants to be 0-1.0 or 0-255.  Most sources talk about 0-1.0 -- but getImageData() returns 0-255... and I can't make it work either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use context.globalAlpha instead of using rgba fill:**

```
p = ground.ctx.getImageData(loc.x, loc.y, 1, 1).data; 
col = {R: p[0], G: p[1], B: p[2], a: p[3]};

// note: globalAlpha uses a scale of 0-1
// and getImageData uses a scale of 0-255
ground.ctx.globalAlpha = a/255-.1;

ground.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + col.R + ', ' + col.G + ', ' + col.B + ')';
ground.ctx.fillRect(nuLoc.x, nuLoc.y, sqrSize, sqrSize);

// reset globalAlpha when you're done
ground.ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
```

Comment: Ahh, fantastic; thanks so much.  I was aware of globalAlpha but hadn't looked into it, as it seemed so... global....  Sort of seems like you shouldn't go changing the world just to get your tie straight.  Now if anyone can explain why it's a good idea for different parts of the api to be using unrelated scales, I'd be very grateful for that information too.