# Javascript - getImageData on canvas always returns alpha 255

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to read the alpha values in an image with javascript and canvas, but the alpha part of the ImageData returned by getImageData is always 255 even if the processed image only consists of transparent pixels. This is what i did:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "url/to/an/image/with/transparency";
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
var data = context.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height).data;
for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i+=4){
    console.log(data[i+3]);
}
```

This always outputs 255. I already found this, but it didn't really help me:
[newbie keeps losing alpha values in canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841434/newbie-keeps-losing-alpha-values-in-canvas)

No matter what i try, it wont work.

**EDIT: This is my full code: http://pastebin.com/3giQCWvP**

The mistakes occur inside the generateCollisionGrid() function. I found out that red and green are also always 255.

This is the image i used for testing: https://addons.opera.com/media/extensions/03/1303/1.4-rev1/icons/icon_64x64.png

Comment: What's with the `while` loop, you already have a handler for when the image has loaded ?

Comment: `while(!ready){}` => infinite loop ?

Comment: @adeneo Thanks, i forgot that i removed this part from my code.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and found that I needed to set the `context.globalCompositeOperation = "copy"` to ensure that the alpha overrode the destination data.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible issues with your code:

- The image might not really be transparent.
- The image might not be fully loaded when you try to draw it. Use `img.onload` to wait until the img is fully loaded before trying to draw it.
- When you `createElement('canvas')` the default size of the canvas is 300x150 so your image is probably larger or smaller than the default canvas size. Use `canvas.width=img.width` & `canvas.height=img.height` to set the canvas size to the img size.
- If the image URL is from a different domain than the web page then a security error will be raised. This error condition will prevent `.getImageData` from returning data.

Here's your code refactored to avoid those issues:

```js
var img=new Image();
img.crossOrigin='anonymous';
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/icon_64x64.png";
function start(){

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    canvas.width=img.width;
    canvas.height=img.height;
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var data = context.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height).data;
    var alphas=''; // demo purposes
    for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i+=4){
        console.log(data[i+3]);
        if(i<200){alphas+=data[i+3]+',';} // demo purposes
    }

    alert(alphas); // demo purposes
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I changed my code according to your example, i just don't append the canvas to my document body. I still get 255 as alpha.

Comment: Please post your image.

Comment: I just printed all rgba values to my console, and they are all wrong, red, green and alpha are always 255 and blue is always 153.

This is the Image i used:
https://addons.opera.com/media/extensions/03/1303/1.4-rev1/icons/icon_64x64.png

Comment: Is your img valid inside `generateCollisionGrid`? As a test (inside generateCollisionGrid), appendChild the img to the page and copy to your desktop. Does the desktop image look non-transparent?

Comment: @serious-scribbler. I've changed my demo to use your image. The results are appropriate (not all 255). :-) Maybe an older version of the image is hung up in your cache? Try clearing your cache with Ctrl-F5 (or in your dev tools).

Comment: Only the first point and this last one in comments could produce 255 alpha values. Not loaded image : 0,0,0,0 ; out of canvas area : 0,0,0,0 ; tainted canvas : Security Error (hence no image data)

Comment: @Kaiido. Of course, but I'm pointing out several weak points in the code ... not just the proximate ones. :-)